# Cuando hago click en mi JButton, la acción se realiza dos veces

Tags: java

Quiero crear un mazo de cartas. Debe ser 108 cartas, con un ciclo for llamo a la rutina generarCarta, la cual crea una carta y la inserta en el mazo. En la rutina generarCarta defino cuál es la acción que esa carta debe tomar, la cual dependerá del atributo campo de esa carta en específico. Todas las cartas se inician con el valor "mazo" por defecto, una vez en mano, ese valor se cambia a "mano".

```
public Carta(int valor, String color, String descripcion, String ruta) {
        this.valor = valor;
        this.color = color;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.ruta = ruta;
        disenoCarta(ruta);
        setTamanoCarta(XtamDefecto, YtamDefecto);
    }

public void disenoCarta(String ruta) {
        disenoBoton();
        disenoEtiqueta(ruta);
    }

public void disenoBoton() {
        boton = new Boton();
    }

    public void disenoEtiqueta(String ruta) {
        etiqueta = new Etiqueta(ruta);
    }

private void generarCarta(int valor, String color, String descripcion, String ruta) {
        Carta nuevaCarta = new Carta(valor, color, descripcion, ruta);
        controladorCarta.setBotonEVENTO(nuevaCarta);
        insertarAlMazo(nuevaCarta);
    }

public void insertarAlMazo(Carta carta) {
        Mazo.mazo.add(carta);
    }

public void setBotonEVENTO(Carta carta) {
        MouseListener oyenteBoton = new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (carta.posicion.equals("mazo"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "mazo");
                // controladorJuego.cargarCarta();
                else if (carta.posicion.equals("mano"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "mano");
                else if (carta.posicion.equals("actual"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "actual");
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

        };
        carta.boton.addMouseListener(oyenteBoton);
    }
```

Comment: El código parece correcto. Una cosa que yo probaría es ver si en algún sitio estás añadiendo otro listener a la carta (por ejemplo invocando `setBotonEVENTO`). En el `mouseClicked`, muestra `this.hashCode()` para ver si la instancia del listener es la misma en cada invocación.

Comment: Sí, eso estaba haciendo, no me habia dado cuenta, ni sabia que se podia añadir más de un listener a un jbutton